# Python: setting value of attribute

Tags: python, attributes

In [this](http://python-ev3dev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/motors.html) API, it says the following regarding setting a motor's polarity:

polarity

Sets the polarity of the motor. 
With normal polarity, a positive duty cycle will cause the motor to rotate clockwise. 
With inversed polarity, a positive duty cycle will cause the motor to rotate counter-clockwise. 
Valid values are normal and inversed.

```
import ev3dev.ev3 as ev3
import numpy as numpy
m = ev3.LargeMotor('outA')
time = numpy.random.normal(loc=5.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
time = time * 1000
speed = 180 / ( time / 1000 )
m.run_timed(time_sp=time, speed_sp=speed)
m.polarity = 'inverse'
time = numpy.random.normal(loc=5.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
time = time * 1000
speed = 180 / ( time / 1000 )
m.run_timed(time_sp=5000, speed_sp=100)
```

m.polarity = 'inverse' doesn't work:

```
robot@ev3dev:~$ python gaussian_motor.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gaussian_motor.py", line 8, in <module>
    m.polarity = 'inverse'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ev3dev/core.py", line 388, in polarity
    self.set_attr_string('polarity', value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ev3dev/core.py", line 216, in set_attr_string
    self._set_attribute(attribute, "{0}".format(value))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ev3dev/core.py", line 204, in _set_attribute
    self._attribute_cache.write(abspath(self._path + '/' + attribute), value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ev3dev/core.py", line 91, in write
    f.write(value.encode())
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Valid values are normal and inverse**d**. (Emphasis mine)

You forgot the d.

Also it looks like `polarity` is a method for setting the polarity.  You may need to access it like `motor.polarity('inversed')`

Comment: No, that documentation would have listed it as `polarity(...)` if it was a method.

Comment: @chepner you're right.  I was confused because a lot of them use words usually associated with functions, like return